# Mailer-Daemon message delay notices incomplete

Tags: macos, ichat

Recently I started getting messages like this in my Messages app.

[image: Mailer-Daemon notification]

Can someone help me understand what is happening and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you **do not** host anything at inmotionhosting.com then it is spam. You should block and report the sender of the message.

If you host at inmotionhosting.com you should ask your hosting provider why you are getting these messages.